# HTML, and CSS for Breaking news ticker

Tags: html, css, animation

I am struggling to get the word "Breaking" to be centered in the Box it is in. I am also struggling getting the scrolling to be continuous, right now there is too much of a delay. I would also like the "Breaking", and the "TEST" headline to stand out, and be more bold. Right now the coding is done, and it works. Just a few minor tweaks. Also is it possible to make whatever I type into "breaking"and test" be a link as well?

```css
.breaking-news-headline {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.breaking-news-title {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 10;
    left: -12px;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #FFEA00;
  }
  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    right: -12px;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 30px solid #FFEA00;
  }
}

#breaking-news-colour {
  height: 30px;
  width: 2394px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

#breaking-news-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.delay-animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.scroll-animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.delay-animated2 {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.delay-animated3 {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.fadein {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
  -moz-animation-name: fadein;
  -o-animation-name: fadein;
  animation-name: fadein;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    margin-left: 1000px
  }
  to {}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    margin-left: 1000px
  }
  to {}
}

.slidein {
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;
  -o-animation-name: slidein;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

.marquee {
  animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10a;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 800px
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0px
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 800px
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0px
  }
}

.slideup {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideup;
  -moz-animation-name: slideup;
  -o-animation-name: slideup;
  animation-name: slideup;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideup {
  from {
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideup {
  from {
    margin-top: 30px
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="breaking-news-container">
  <div id="breaking-news-colour" class="slideup animated">
  </div>
  <span class="breaking-news-title delay-animated slidein">
      BREAKING
    </span>
  <a class="breaking-news-headline delay-animated2 fadein marquee">
      TEST
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am struggling to get the word "Breaking" to be centered in the Box it is in

```
.breaking-news-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 7px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

delete → padding-left: 0px;

> I would also like the "Breaking", and the "TEST" headline to stand
>   out, and be more bold.

just add font-weight: bold;

> Also is it possible to make whatever I type into "breaking"and test"
>   be a link as well? Thanks!

yes, replace your span to `<a>` tag and your "TEST" is already `<a>` tag

and by the way according to caniuse.com `<marquee>` tag is deprecated so you should not use it

http://caniuse.com/#search=marquee

but here is the edit I made
https://jsfiddle.net/gs8p0zc3/

use this css3 animation instead of marquee

**EDIT** made similar design of your code
https://jsfiddle.net/sfjjvpk5/1/

Comment: Thank you so very much, I used yours instead as it is way better. I really appreciate your help, been working on this for so long. Just started learning HTML, CSS. THANKS! <3

Comment: @aerebourne alright, glad that I helped you, enjoy your coding :)